# Is this a bug in the MvcContrib TestHelper OutBoundUrl class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am trying to test the outbound URL of an action method in an MVC area using the MvcContrib TestHelper's static `OutBoundUrl` class. Here is what I have:

```
OutBoundUrl.Of<ErrorsController>(action => action.NotFound())
    .ShouldMapToUrl("/errors/404");
```

I stepped into the source and found that the `UrlHelper` was returning null for the outbound URL. Basically it creates a new UrlHelper and delegates the task to `UrlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues)`.

When invoked, `routeValues` does not contain anything (the action method takes no args). Is this a bug? Or do I need to do something extra to make this work with areas? The following line comes just before the above line in the unit test, so my routes are registered (the `UrlHelper.RouteCollection` contains 100+ routes).

```
"~/errors/404".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Get)
    .ShouldMapTo<ErrorsController>(action => action.NotFound());
```

The route is not named, and I don't want to name it, so please don't suggest I use the `OfRouteNamed` method.

**Update**

I made an extension method that could work, except for one thing. The `OutBoundController` `Of<TController>` method has this code:

```
var methodCall = ((MethodCallExpression)action.Body);
var methodName = methodCall.Method.Name;
```

There is similar, but critically different code in the `RouteTestingExtensions` `ShouldMapTo<TController>` method:

```
var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) action.Body;
// this line is not important
string expectedAction = methodCall.Method.ActionName();
```

The `ActionName()` extension method is kind of awesome if you use `ActionNameAttributes`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will return the name of the action specified in the ActionNameAttribute 
/// for a method if it has an ActionNameAttribute.
/// Will return the name of the method otherwise.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="method"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ActionName(this MethodInfo method)
{
    if (method.IsDecoratedWith<ActionNameAttribute>()) 
        return method.GetAttribute<ActionNameAttribute>().Name;

    return method.Name;
}
```

Back to the question... is this by design, and if so, why? The fact that `OutBoundUrl` does not use the `.ActionName()` extension is the one thing keeping me from writing an extension method to generate outbound url's for area actions decorated with `[ActionName]`.